# Change docstring max line length while preserving newlines, indents, and words

Tags: python, string, multiline

Given a function docstring, I seek to reduce its max line length. My attempt preserves newlines, indents, and words (doesn't break words), but fails to actually enforce max line length. My other attempts enforce length but fail at preserving, and code tends to complicate fast.

Autopep8 appears to have an [unfixed bug](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8/issues/497) since 2019.

I need an automated way to change docstring max length - overwriting target file allowed. Am I missing something simple with `textwrap`, or is there any other module/utility?

#### Attempt

```py
import textwrap

def change_maxlen(txt):
    # hard-coded stuff (e.g. `76`) for demo simplicity
    tnew = ["    "]
    for l in txt.splitlines():
        wrap = textwrap.fill(l[4:], width=76)
        if '\n' in wrap:
            pnew = "\n    " + wrap.replace('\n', ' ')
        else:
            pnew = "\n    " + wrap
        tnew += [pnew]
    tnew = "".join(tnew).replace('"""', '')
    return tnew
```

Many other failed attempts...

#### Example input

```
    """Compute spatial support of `pf` as the interval, in number of samples,
    where sum of envelope (absolute value) inside it is `1 / criterion_amplitude`
    times greater than outside.

    Used for avoiding boundary effects and incomplete filter decay. Accounts for
    tail decay, but with lessser weight than the Heisgenberg resolution measure
    for monotonic decays (i.e. no bumps/spikes). For prioritizing the main lobe,
    see `dumdum.utils.measures.compute_temporal_width()`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    pf : np.ndarray, 1D
        Filter, in frequency domain.

        Assumes that the time-domain waveform, `ifft(pf)`, is centered at index

    guarantee_decay : bool (default False)
        In practice, this is identical to `True`, though `True` will still return

    Returns
    -------
    support : int
        Total temporal support of `pf`, measured in samples ("total" as opposed to
        only right or left part).
    """
```

#### Desired output

```
    """Compute spatial support of `pf` as the interval, in number of samples,
    where sum of envelope (absolute value) inside it is `1 / 
    criterion_amplitude` times greater than outside.
    
    Used for avoiding boundary effects and incomplete filter decay. Accounts 
    for tail decay, but with lessser weight than the Heisgenberg resolution 
    measure for monotonic decays (i.e. no bumps/spikes). For prioritizing the 
    main lobe, see `dumdum.utils.measures.compute_temporal_width()`.
     
    Parameters
    ----------
    pf : np.ndarray, 1D
        Filter, in frequency domain.
    
        Assumes that the time-domain waveform, `ifft(pf)`, is centered at index
    
    guarantee_decay : bool (default False)
        In practice, this is identical to `True`, though `True` will still 
        return
    
    Returns
    -------
    support : int
        Total temporal support of `pf`, measured in samples ("total" as opposed
        to only right or left part).
    """
```

Comment: In vim, if you set `:set textwidth=72` and then `gqip`, it should format that paragraph to the max line length. Of course, this may not help for larger codebases...

Comment: I'll try, thanks. One file/direct string input is fine.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq That's too much learning for this one thing for me, but I somehow figured out (Windows & key-remapped install) `Esc` to enter the `:set textwidth=72`, then `Enter`, then I type `gqip`, and it does something, but not what it should. But I'm probably doing it wrong.

Comment: The cursor needs to be on the paragraph. `gqip` means to apply wrapping to `i`nner `p`aragraph, i.e. the paragraph that the cursor is on. Alternatively, you can visually select via `Vjjjj` then `gq`.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I see, yes, it fails to preserve indent.

Comment: I guess `:set autoindent` is probably needed beforehand in addition to `:set textwidth=72`.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it from scratch - far from performance-optimized, and has important unhandled cases, but it's something. Tested on more challenging and much longer docstrings than in OP.

I also tried having ChatGPT-3.5 rewrite my solution or make one from scratch, also tried every non-GPT4 option on platform.openai - everything failed miserably. I wrote my prompts carefully. GPT4 requires having already paid $1 in usage (...instead of just having me pay $1 to unlock?)

**UNSATISFACATORY SOLUTION!** Sharing cause better than nothing.

##### Usage

**(1)** `max_len`: target maximum number of characters per line.

**(2)** `base_indent=4`: shared minimum indent of all lines. Lesser indents are cropped. If the true `base_indent` is greater, the code still works, but final indent may be off.

**(3)** Input strings must be wrapped by another multiline string. So, if we want to reformat

```py
    """Blah blah
    rasengan
    """
```

we do

```py
txt = '''    """Blah blah
    rasengan
    """'''
```

that is, start with

```py
txt = ''''''
```

then copy the full original string, and paste it right between `'''` and `'''`.

##### Unhandled cases

An unhandled case is overflowing bullets, so

```py
    """
    Normal line

        - Indented bullet ...
          continuation ...
```

if the `Indented bullet` line exceeds `max_len`, then `continuation` will vertically align with `-` rather than `I`. Other cases:

- Nested bullets with newlines between - the newlines are dropped
- Words longer than `max_len`
- Probably others

#### Sanity check

To check that any given function didn't toss out any part of input string, we can run

#### Code

Included is a universal sanity check that a method doesn't toss out any characters or add new ones (asserts equality on flattened strings).

```py
def change_max_len(txt, max_len, base_indent, sanity_check=True):
    def body(new_lines, carry, current_indent, l):
        l_orig = l
        l_indent = len(l) - len(l.lstrip())
        if l not in ("", '"""', "'''"):
            current_indent = l_indent
        extra_newline = False
    
        if carry != "":
            if l_orig in ('"""', "'''"):
                l = " "*current_indent + carry + "\n    " + l_orig
            elif l_indent > 0 or l_orig == "":
                l = " "*current_indent + carry + " " + l[l_indent:]
                if l_orig == "":
                    extra_newline = True
            else:
                l = carry + " " + l
            carry = ""
        
        def handle_overflow(l, new_lines):
            words = l.split(" ")
    
            l0 = ""
            l1 = ""
            for w in words:
                w_add = " " + w
                # `-1` as later we drop a `" "`
                if len(l0) + len(w_add) - 1 <= max_len_adj:
                    l0 += w_add
                else:
                    l1 += w_add
            # drop the first `" "`
            l0, l1 = l0[1:], l1[1:]
    
            carry = l1
    
            assert len(l0) <= max_len_adj
            new_line = "    " + l0 + "\n"
            return new_line, carry
    
    
        if len(l) <= max_len_adj:
            new_line = " "*base_indent + l + "\n"
        else:
            new_line, carry = handle_overflow(l, new_lines)
            # handle over-overflow
            if len(carry) / max_len_adj > 2:
                new_lines += [new_line]
                l = carry
                i = 0
                while True:
                    new_line, carry = handle_overflow(l, new_lines)
                    if len(carry) / max_len_adj <= 2:
                        break
                    new_lines += [new_line]
                    l = carry
                    i += 1
                    if i > 10:
                        # probably a single word in excess of max_len_adj
                        raise Exception("`max_len` probably too small")
                        
        if extra_newline:
            new_line += "\n"
     
        new_lines += [new_line]
    
        return new_lines, carry, current_indent

    max_len_adj = max_len - base_indent
    # first dedent then reindent
    lines = [l[base_indent:] for l in txt.splitlines()]
    
    # initialze loop values
    new_lines = []
    carry = ""
    current_indent = 0
    
    # main loop
    for i, l in enumerate(lines):
        new_lines, carry, current_indent = body(
            new_lines, carry, current_indent, l)
    
    new_txt = "".join(new_lines)

    # sanity check
    def flatten_str(x):
        return "".join("".join(w) for l in txt.splitlines()
                       for w in l.split())

    assert flatten_str(new_txt) == flatten_str(txt)

    return new_txt

txt = '''    """Compute spatial support of `pf` as the interval, in number of samples,
    where sum of envelope (absolute value) inside it is `1 / criterion_amplitude`
    times greater than outside.

    Used for avoiding boundary effects and incomplete filter decay. Accounts for
    tail decay, but with lessser weight than the Heisgenberg resolution measure
    for monotonic decays (i.e. no bumps/spikes). For prioritizing the main lobe,
    see `dumdum.utils.measures.compute_temporal_width()`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    pf : np.ndarray, 1D
        Filter, in frequency domain.

        Assumes that the time-domain waveform, `ifft(pf)`, is centered at index

    guarantee_decay : bool (default False)
        In practice, this is identical to `True`, though `True` will still return

    Returns
    -------
    support : int
        Total temporal support of `pf`, measured in samples ("total" as opposed to
        only right or left part).
    """'''

new_txt = change_max_len(txt, max_len=70, base_indent=4)
print(new_txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

A vim-based manual editing method:

0. Set `:set textwidth=72` and `:set autoindent`.
1. Select text via `V`.
2. Wrap text via `gq`.

[Video demonstration](https://asciinema.org/a/AP4tSaHagVWN25BKhNEDzY7f9?t=3), which does the following:

```
:set textwidth=72
:set autoindent

j     (move down)
Vjj   (select text)
gq    (wrap text)

:wq   (save and quit)
```

Comment: Thanks for the demo, but this only works per manually skipping the lines it fails to handle, at which point it's faster to do it manually the normal way. If I select the whole docstring, it makes a mess. Also anything with more steps than this but the whole docstring selected would be too slow, but it's fair to share it.